# jails in zfs space in freebsd 11, gives mount descfs error

Tags: freebsd, patch-management, jail

Good Night, I am trying to deply a multijail environment using freebsd 11 on a OVH dedicated server.

I created the cloned interfaces and created the jail , but as soon as I try to start it tells me that can not mount nullfs.

I added this to /boot/loader.conf

```
nullfs_mount=1
```

restarted but now gives me a second error

```
Starting jails: cannot start jail  "haproxy": 
mount: .: Operation not supported by device
jail: haproxy: /sbin/mount -t fdescfs . /local/jails/haproxy/dev/fd: failed
```

I applyed the patch described in

```
https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2014-August/079700.html
```

and located here

```
http://pastebin.com/5t9zEzkV
```

Applying this command

```
#patch /sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c sys_fs_fdescfs_fdesc_vfsop
```

But it fails loudly like this:

```
Hmm...  Looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c b/sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c
|index cb5e3c0..7193809 100644
|--- a/sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c
|+++ b/sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c
--------------------------
Patching file /sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c using Plan A...
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [y] y
Hunk #1 succeeded at 51 (offset 1 line).
Hunk #2 failed at 79.
No such line 241 in input file, ignoring
Hunk #3 succeeded at 229 (offset -8 lines).
1 out of 3 hunks failed--saving rejects to /sys/fs/fdescfs/fdesc_vfsops.c.rej
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/sys/kern/kern_jail.c b/sys/kern/kern_jail.c
|index 2846eca..791723d 100644
|--- a/sys/kern/kern_jail.c
|+++ b/sys/kern/kern_jail.c
--------------------------
File to patch: /sys/kern/kern_jail.c
Patching file /sys/kern/kern_jail.c using Plan A...
Hunk #1 failed at 207.
Hunk #2 failed at 224.
Hunk #3 failed at 4247.
Hunk #4 failed at 4403.
4 out of 4 hunks failed--saving rejects to /sys/kern/kern_jail.c.rej
Hmm...  The next patch looks like a unified diff to me...
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/sys/sys/jail.h b/sys/sys/jail.h
|index a82a499..a01d665 100644
|--- a/sys/sys/jail.h
|+++ b/sys/sys/jail.h
--------------------------
File to patch: /sys/sys/jail.h
Patching file /sys/sys/jail.h using Plan A...
Hunk #1 failed at 228.
1 out of 1 hunks failed--saving rejects to /sys/sys/jail.h.rej
done
#
```

Has anybody found this error in Freebsd 11, anyone could help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The patch is for 10.x in the two years ago state, you're applying it to 11.x as of now, no wonder it fails. You should ask the author to port it to the 11.x, and probably, investigate why it wasn't commited to the tree in the first place - I'm sure it had it's reason not to.

P.S. SO doesn't seem the right place to ask this question, the appropriate one would be the *freebsd-stable@* mailing list.